# convert html form data to pdf in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

How can I export my html form to pdf and show it in pdf form on button click

My form:

```
<form>
    {% for a in test %}
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>{{a}}</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input aria-label="" value="{{ a|get_at_index:forloop.counter0 }}" readonly>
        <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">gm</span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
 ......
</form>
```

I don't want to convert whole html to pdf, just the form. How can I export the form after getting data to pdf and show it on button click ? Is it possible to get pdf in form of table i.e. row and column ?

Comment: check this article. with python you can easily deal with pdfs https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-pdf-files-with-python-ad3ccadfae0f